# perl process queue

Tags: perl, multiprocessing

I have a Perl script which forks a number of sub-processes.  I'd like to have some kind of functionality like `xargs --max-procs=4 --max-args=1` or `make -j 4`, where Perl will keep a given number of processes running until it runs out of work.

It's easy to say fork four process and wait for them all to complete, and then fork another four, but I'd like to keep four or n processes running at the same time, forking a new process as soon as one completes.

Is there a simple way in Perl to implement such a process pool?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`Forks::Super`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Forks::Super) can handle this requirement.

```
use Forks::Super MAX_PROC => 5, ON_BUSY => [ block | queue ];
```

Calls to `fork()` can block until the number of active subprocesses falls below 5, or you can pass additional parameters to the `fork` call and the tasks to perform can queue up:

```
fork { sub => sub { ... task to run in subprocess ... } }
```

When one subprocess finishes, another job on the queue will start up.

(I am the author of this module).

Comment: What is the difference between block and queue?

Comment: `block` will make your program wait until some child processes finish so that the next task can start. `queue` will put the current task in a queue and let your program keep running. Jobs on the queue will be started asynchronously when other child processes finish.

Comment: is there a way to keep the forked processes alive as a pool while they wait for more jobs to be queued? I queue my jobs in batches and then report output, but I'd like the forked processes to stay alive.

Comment: On Perl 5.30 this module fails test when installed through CPAN due to the deprecation of `sysread()` on `:utf8` handles. The test is `t/44l-pipes.t`.

Answer (score 6):

Check out [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel::ForkManager) -- it does much of what you describe.  You can set a maximum number of processes, and the callback function could start a new child as soon as one finishes (as long as there is work to do).

Answer (score 3):

While I would almost always use a CPAN module, or write something with the fantastic AnyEvent modules I think its important to understand how these things work under the hood.  Here's an example that has no dependencies other than perl.  The same approach could also be written in C without too much trouble.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;

## run a function in a forked process
sub background (&) {
  my $code = shift;

  my $pid = fork;
  if ($pid) {
    return $pid;
  } elsif ($pid == 0) {
    $code->();
    exit;
  } else{
    die "cant fork: $!"
  }
}

my @work = ('sleep 30') x 8;
my %pids = ();
for (1..4) {
  my $w = shift @work;
  my $pid = background {
    exec $w;
  };
  $pids{$pid} = $w; 
}

while (my $pid = waitpid(-1,0)) {
  if ($?) {
    if ($? & 127) {
      warn "child died with signal " . ($? & 127);
    } else {
      warn "chiled exited with value " . ($? >> 8);
    }

    ## redo work that died or got killed
    my $npid = background {
      exec $pids{$pid};
    };
    $pids{$npid} = delete $pids{$pid};
  } else {
    delete $pids{$pid};

    ## send more work if there is any
    if (my $w = shift @work) {
      my $pid = background {
        exec shift @work;
      };
      $pids{$pid} = $w;
    }
  }
}
```