# How to do parallel programming in perl on Windows?

Tags: windows, multithreading, perl, parallel-processing, fork

I have used the following pattern of code in perl on a Unix system, but it crashes on Windows.  How can I achieve the same thing using either forking or threads on Windows using perl?

```
use Parallel::ForkManager;

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new($MAX_PROCESSES);

DATA_LOOP:
foreach my $data (@all_data) {
    # Forks and returns the pid for the child:
    my $pid = $pm->start and next DATA_LOOP;

    # ... do some work with $data in the child process ...

    $pm->finish; # Terminates the child process
}
```

Comment: [Thread::Queue](http://p3rl.org/Thread::Queue)

Comment: What would be the equivalent of the above code using `Thread::Queue`?

Comment: @choroba It didn't work either. Crashes as well.

Comment: [Forks::Super](http://search.cpan.org/~mob/Forks-Super-0.68/lib/Forks/Super.pm) by @mob should work on Windows. Also note its [tips for windows](http://search.cpan.org/~mob/Forks-Super-0.68/lib/Forks/Super.pm#Special_tips_for_Windows_systems). Try [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424778/perl-process-queue)

Comment: sounds like your perl installation has some problems.  tell more about the crashing

Comment: @ysth I have tried a new perl installation of both ActiveState and Strawberry perl and the problem still occurs.  It says `perl command line interpreter has stopped working`.

Comment: Does a simple hello world work in ActiveState or Strawberry? `perl -e"print 'hello world'"`

Comment: `Parallel::ForkManager` has always worked well for me with `perl`s I have built and `perl`s I have installed via Strawberry or ActiveState distributions. There is a problem with either the code you are not showing us or your installation. Are you making sure you `$pm->wait_all_children;`?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot  Yes, everything else works, it's just forking and threads - forks in Windows being threads anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one example using fork:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;


foreach my $data (@all_data) {
    my $pid;
    next if $pid = fork;    # Parent goes to next server.
    die "fork failed: $!" unless defined $pid;

    # From here on, we're in the child.  Do whatever the
    # child has to do...  The server we want to deal
    # with is in $data.

    exit;  # Ends the child process.
}

# The following waits until all child processes have
# finished, before allowing the parent to die.

1 while (wait() != -1);

print "All done!\n";
```

Comment: That's not quite the same because it spawns `scalar(@all_data)` processes all at once. The OP's example spawns no more than `$MAX_PROCESSES` processes at a time.